# Microcontroller JTAG debugging

Tags: debugging, microcontroller

I was going through various methods of debugging and stumbled upon a question. In step by step debugging using breakpoints, IDE GUI provides the register values and memory location values for verification for each step of program.I wanted to know are these values fetched from the Microcontroller hardware through JTAG or is it simply virtual simulation results by mimicking the microcontroller core in the Host computer? Is there any methodology to control the live program execution in microcontroller through IDE and see the live values of registers and memory locations for live debugging.

Comment: Answers are: Fetched from MUC and not simulated. Yes, execution can be controlled and live values can monitored. This is what JTAG is for. I'm assuming this is an academic question as you don't specify any particular MCU.

Comment: @code Thanks for your response. Can you brief the background information about what happens when each instruction is stepped into IDE how it is reflected in MCU i.e. is it that instruction into converted into hex code and sent to MCU for execution or a command is sent to MCU to fetch the equivalent hexcode from program memory and sent for execution?

Comment: Breakpoints are a feature of the MCU. The MCU will automatically stop if it hits a breakpoints and notify the debugger via JTAG about it. Single stepping also uses a breakpoint. Commands transmitted via JTAG allow the debugger to set and delete breakpoints, read and modify memory, read registers etc. JTAG is a binary protocol. "Hexcodes" are only used in the UI of the debugger.

Comment: @codo I know that synchronization happens between flash tool and MCU while loading a hex file into MCU. I was more interested about synchronization between IDE and MCU during debugging i.e. say in 100 line code and break point is set at line7 in the IDE. How does IDE debugger determines the timing at which break point command needs to sent through JTAG? In other words how would debugger know that instruction in line 6 is being executed in MCU and hence next a break point command needs to be sent for halting the execution process of MCU.

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in the IDE, the IDE sends the address of the breakpoint to the MCU. The MCU then handles the breakpoint itself. It will stop when the code execution reaches the breakpoint, and it then notifies the IDE that is has stopped at a breakpoint. The IDE does not need to do anything actively.

Comment: Great. I will summarise, correct me if I am wrong. IDE is developed to create a program and build. Hex code is generated which is flashed into MCU. Now MCU doesn't function as expected and a debug session is initiated. Breakpoint is set in IDE and address of breakpoint is sent to MCU. In return MCU stalls the operation and sends the value of registers and memory location to IDE for debugging.

Comment: Great. I will summarise, correct me if I am wrong. IDE is developed to create a program and build. Hex code is generated which is flashed into MCU. Now MCU doesn't function as expected and a debug session is initiated. Breakpoint is set in IDE and address of breakpoint is sent to MCU. In return MCU stalls the operation and sends the value of registers and memory location to IDE for debugging.

Comment: That's about right.

Comment: What IDE are you talking about?  There is more than one, you know.  What part are you trying to debug?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you need to understand first what debugging means. In debug mode the computer sets break points (program entry address) where the microcontroller need to stop and give back the status to the IDE.
In your case the register values and memory status is fetched directly from the microcontroller when it reach the break point.
JTAG debuggers are varied with many functions depending on the combination of hardware and software you use.
Choosing the right debugger is not an easy task when it come to advanced programming and realtime debugging/tracing. I recommend you to check https://www.tmartis.com/en/34-debugger-programmers for more details about the most used JTAG debuggers.
Hope that i had answered your question.